# How to save the recent access data in tree view

Tags: android

I have not much experience at Android (and sorry for my english not good). I am so confused at saving the recent access data in a tree view.

This is the example of process when I access data:[image]

Activity1 have two Tabs: **Pages** and **Recent**. When I click on one node (Folder A) at Tab **Pages**, it would show all the children of that node on another Activity and so on.

I want to display the recent access route in Tab **Recent**, something like this: ***Folder A -> Folder A3 -> Folder A3.3 -> ... ->Folder An*** . How can I do that?

I used *startActivityForResult* but the results respond only when the previous activity was finished. 
I also used *SharedPreference* to save that access route but this way seem not that good and reloading is needed when updating the route in **Tab Recent**.

Please give me some advise and ideas what exactly methods I must do?

Thank you very much and I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are facing two problems:

1. Find a way of storing route data and sharing it between Activities.
2. Display all that data in a tree view with out reloading the **Recent Tab** .

Here is my Solution:

1. Keep all the data in the memory.

   You can use a Singleton Class to hold up the data sharing logic.

   ```
   class Singleton {
       ...
       public TreeNode mTopRootNode;
       public getTopRootNode() {
          if(topRootNode == null) {
              mTopRootNode = TreeNode.root();
          }
          return mTopRootNode;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Use this [AndroidTreeView Library](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView).
3. Create a root node when user navigates to the **Tab Pages**:

   ```
   TreeNode child = new TreeNode("Tab");
   Singleton.getInstance().getTopRootNode().addChild(child);
   ```
4. Add a node when user navigation to other node let's say ActivityA:

   ```
   TreeNode parent = traversalTheTreeAndFindParentByName(ActivityA);

   TreeNode child = new TreeNode("ActivityA");

   parent.addChild(child);
   ```
5. When user navigates back to the **Tab Recent**:

   Override the onResume of the **Tab Recent** Activity/Fragment. During onResume fetch the top root node of your tree, then traversal the tree and display it.